# Select Ingredients of a product based on unit type

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have three tables UnitType,NutritionMaster, NutritionInProduct

```
UnitTypeID  UnitName
1           100ml contains
2           250ml contains

NutritionID Name    Description
1           Energy  NULL
2           Protein NULL

ID                    NutritionID  ProductID     UnitTypeID Unit
54087                       1       20785           1       2ml(0.5 kcal)
54088                       1       20785           2       4ml
54089                       2       20785           1       10ml
54090                       2       20785           2       50ml
```

And I want to show the results as

[image]

I tried doing it like this

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY unittypeid ORDER BY NutritionInProductid aSC) AS "Row Number",
NutritionInProductid,unittypeid,ProductID,unit from NutritionInProduct
group by  unittypeid,NutritionInProductid,ProductID,unittypeid,unit
having ProductID =20785
```

but its not what I want ..can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer looks something like this:

```
SELECT nip.ProductID, n.Name, ut.UnitName, nip.Unit
FROM NutritionInProduct AS nip
INNER JOIN NutritionMaster AS n ON nip.NutritionID=n.NutritionID
INNER JOIN UnitType AS ut ON nip.UnitTypeID=ut.UnitTypeID
WHERE nip.ProductID=20785
ORDER BY nip.ProductID, n.Name, ut.UnitName;
```

I have intentionally not pivoted the results because the PIVOT syntax needs you to hard-code the names of the columns, which in this case are dynamically defined in the UnitType table.

While we're at it, you may wish to consider a few revisions to your schema:

- There are some naming issues that can confuse other developers, for instance the "Unit" column should probably be called "Content" or something a bit more accurate.
- "Unit" should probably also be numeric.
- The unit of "Unit" (i.e. grams, ml, etc) is a property of the "NutritionMaster" table. For instance, for "Energy", the unit is "kcal" or "J", while for proteins, carbs, etc, the unit property is "grams", and so on.
- NutritionMaster should probably be called something like ProductContents or ProductValues.
- Consider adding a "quantity" column to the product, so you can calculate the numbers dynamically. In your example, you've stored the 100g and 60g values in duplicate - ideally, you would want to store just the 100g values, and then multiply those by (60/100).

Here's how I would design a similar solution:

```
--- A table for all the products:
CREATE TABLE dbo.Product (
    ID          int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ProductName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    ServingSize int NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Product (ID, ProductName, ServingSize)
VALUES (20785, 'Spring rolls, oven cooked', 60);

--- A table for the different measures (these are the "rows" in your output)
CREATE TABLE dbo.ContentType (
    ID          int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ContentType varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    UnitName    varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.ContentType (ID, ContentType, UnitName)
VALUES (1, 'Energy', 'kcal'),
       (2, 'Protein', 'g'),
       (3, 'Carbohydrates', 'g'),
       (4, '.. of which sugars', 'g');

--- And the "fact" table with just the 100g contents:
CREATE TABLE dbo.ProductValues (
    ProductID     int NOT NULL,
    ContentTypeID int NOT NULL,
    Value100g     decimal(10, 1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ProductValues
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ProductID, ContentTypeID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ProductValues_Product
        FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES dbo.Product (ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ProductValues_ContentType
        FOREIGN KEY (ContentTypeID) REFERENCES dbo.ContentType (ID)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.ProductValues (ProductID, ContentTypeID, Value100g)
VALUES (20785, 1, 201.0),   --- Energy, kcal
       (20785, 2, 3.8),     --- Protein, g
       (20785, 3, 28.3),    --- Carbs, g
       (20785, 4, 3.8);     --- ... of which sugars
```

... and here's how to query those tables:

```
SELECT p.ProductName,
       CAST(p.ServingSize AS varchar(10))+' g.' AS ServingSize,
       ct.ContentType AS Content,
       STR(pv.Value100g, 10, 1)+' '+ct.UnitName AS ContentsPer100g,
       STR(pv.Value100g*p.ServingSize/100, 10, 1)+' '+ct.UnitName AS ContentsPerServing
FROM dbo.ProductValues AS pv
INNER JOIN dbo.Product AS p ON pv.ProductID=p.[ID]
INNER JOIN dbo.ContentType AS ct ON pv.ContentTypeID=ct.ID;
```